# Web application running in different application pool - how to access website resources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

For one of the NPO's that I am designing my application for, there is also a website which is not designed by me. The website consists of static HTML pages, where as my application (Blood Donor Management System) is designed in ASP.Net MVC. The Blood Donor Management System will be running in a separate application pool. Here is how the Site will be organized.

IisServer
----NPO WebSite(root)
---------Blood Donor Management System (root/MyAppPath)
----Other Websites (not belonging to my NPO).

The Blood Donor Management System is a back office application for most of its part. The only part that will be exposed to public is the Registration of Blood Donors and viewing their profiles. I am not sure about the following

1. How do I decorate these registration and profile pages using the resources (layout) from the Website, since my application will run in separate application pool.
2. Should I run the website and my application in same application pool. There are only two pages in my application that would need resources(layout related) from the website.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you combine your MVC application into one, and use `Areas` to separate them and still able to utilize shared resources.

[Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx)

Comment: But I have already developed my ASP.net MVC Application and it is not using any areas. How do I move my application into a new area, I mean I am not sure whether this would be a easy task. Or should I create a new area (within my ASP.Net MVC application) for the WebSite instead and import the third party static web site resources into that area. Just a little confused !